# closed form of random variables with exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

There are $k$ number of sorted random variables $X_1 > \cdots > X_k$ with magnitude and they follow exponential distribution $\mu e^{-\mu}$.

I can get the values of $X_1,\cdots,X_k$ with matlab experimentally.

My method is to generate $K$ number of random variables with 1000 iterations and sorting them.
Then, I can find the average values of random variables as
$\overline{X}_1 = \frac{1}{1000}\sum_{i=0}^{1000}X_1^i,\cdots, \overline{X}_k =\frac{1}{1000}\sum_{i=0}^{1000}X_k^i$, where $X_l^i$ is $l$th random variable with magnitude in $i$th iteration

However, I wonder if I can get the values of these random variables mathematically.

My question is to find patterns of random variables $\overline{X}_1, \cdots, \overline{X}_k$.

When $\mu$ and $K$ are known, is there a closed form of sorted random variables $\overline{X}_1, \cdots, \overline{X}_k$?

example) $\overline{X}_1 = \frac{K}{\mu}, X_2 =\frac{K-1}{\mu},\cdots, \overline{X}_k =\frac{1}{\mu} $

Comment: $$E(X_i)=\frac1\mu\sum_{j=i}^k\frac1j$$

Comment: Read this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic (Section: Order statistics sampled from an exponential distribution) It is helpful.